# Apresentar dados do Array na table Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em que calcula a média  em que faço a validação dos campos se estão devidamente preenchidos e se os campos  estiverem preenchidos e a soma das notas for menor que 10 ele passa os dados do inputText para funcão que faz o calculo da media e outra função que retorna o status do aluno se está aprovado,reprovado.Assim guardos os dados digitados em arrays e apresentando em uma table

Mas ao clicar no botão calcular ele apresenta essa mensagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

HTML

```
<body>
<form action="" method="post" class="formcss" name="form1"  >
    <h1>Dados do Aluno<br/>
        <span class="titulo">Por favor, preencha os campos solicitados.</span>
    </h1> 
    <div>&nbsp;</div> 
    <div>
        <div class="rotulos">RGM :</div>
        <input id="rgm" type="text" name="rgm" placeholder="Digite seu RGM" class="entrada" />
    </div>
    <div>
    <div>
        <div class="rotulos">Nome :</div>
        <input id="nome" type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome completo" class="entrada" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <div class="rotulos">Nota parcial :</div>
        <input type="text" id="notaparcial" name="notaparcial" 
               placeholder="Digite aqui a nota parcial" class="entrada" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="rotulos">Nota exercícios :</div>
        <input type="text" id="notaexercicios" name="notaexercicios" 
               placeholder="Digite aqui a nota dos exercícios" class="entrada" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="rotulos">Nota projeto :</div>
        <input type="text" id="notaprojeto" name="notaprojeto" 
               placeholder="Digite aqui a nota no projeto" class="entrada" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="rotulos">Nota regimental :</div>
        <input type="text" id="notaregimental" name="notaregimental" 
               placeholder="Digite aqui a nota regimental" class="entrada" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="rotulos">&nbsp;</div>
        <input type="button" id="btncalcular" value="Calcular" class="botao" />
        <input type="button" id="btnlistar" value="Mostrar" class="botao" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <div id="divresultado" class="rotuloretorno">Resultado...</div>
    </div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div><br>
</form>

</body>
```

CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
.formcss {
width: 55%;
background-color: #865027;
padding: 20px 30px 20px 30px;
font-size: 12px;
font-family: verdana;
color: #fff;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;
border-radius: 25px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
h1 {
padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
text-align: center;
}
.titulo {    
font-size: 11px;
}
div {    
   margin: 0px 0px 20px;
}
.rotulos {
float: left;
width: 20%;
text-align: right;
padding-right: 10px;
margin-top: 10px;
font-weight: bold;
 }
.rotuloretorno {
float: left;
width: 75%;
font-size: 14px;
font-family: verdana;
text-align: left;
padding-left: 200px;
padding-right: 10px;
margin-top: 10px;
font-weight: bold;
}
  .entrada {
border: none;
color: #525252;
height: 30px;
line-height: 15px;    
padding: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
width: 70%;
border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;
background-color: #f5deb3;
}
   .botao {
background-color: #2e1707;
border: none;
padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
color: #fff;
border-radius: 4px;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFE477;
font-weight: bold;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #3D3D3D;
}
   .botao:hover {
color: #dbd9d9;
background-color: #030201;
}    
</style>
```

Funções e Jquery

```
<script>

function validar() {
var nome= $("#nome").val();
var rgm= $("#rgm").val();
var parcial= $("#notaparcial").val();
var exercicios= $("#notaexercicios").val();
var projeto= $("#notaprojeto").val();
var regimental= $("#notaregimental").val();

if(nome == ""){

    alert('Preencha o campo com seu nome');
    form1.nome.focus();
}
else if(rgm == ""){
    alert('Preencha o campo com rgm');
    form1.rgm.focus();

}

else if(parcial == ""){
    alert('Preencha o campo com a nota da parcial');
    form1.rgm.focus();

}

else if(exercicios == ""){
    alert('Preencha o campo com a nota dos exe');
    form1.exercicios.focus();

}

else if(projeto == ""){
alert('Preencha o campo com a nota projeto');
    form1.projeto.focus();

}

else{
    alert('Preencha o campo com a nota regimental');
    form1.notaregimental.focus();

     }
  }

function caculoMedia(n1,n2,n3,n4){
        var media;

    media=(n1+n2+n3+n4)/4;

        return media;
    }

function situacao(n1,n2,n3,n4){
        var situacao="",media;

    media=(n1+n2+n3+n4)/4;

    if(media>=6){
        situacao+="Aprovado";


    }
    else if(media<6){

        situacao+="Exame";
    }
    else{

        situacao+="Reprovado";
    }

        returnsituacao;
    }


var nomes=[];
var indice=[];
  var situacao=[];
  var media=[];

    var i=1;


 window.onload = function(){
    var btn = document.getElementById("btncalcular");
    btn.onclick = function (){
        if(validar){
            if(parcial+exercicios+projeto+regimental<=10){
         nomes[i]=$("#nome").val();
        var parcial= $("#notaparcial").val();
var exercicios= $("#notaexercicios").val();
var projeto= $("#notaprojeto").val();
var regimental= $("#notaregimental").val();

              var resp=caculoMedia(parcial,exercicios,projeto,regimental);
       media[i]=resp;   
                  var situacao=situacao(parcial,exercicios,projeto,regimental);
       situacao[i]=situacao;    

        }
            else{

                alert("A soma das notas não podem ultrapassar 10");
            }


        }
    }

    document.getElementById("btnlistar").onclick=function(){
            listarAlunos();
        }
}



function listarAlunos(){
    var conteudo="<table border='2'>";
     conteudo+="<tr>";
     conteudo+="<th>";
    conteudo+="<div class='aluno'><p>Aluno</p></div>";
      conteudo+="</th>";
    conteudo+="<th>";
    conteudo+="<div class='media'><p>Media</p></div>";
      conteudo+="</th>";
    conteudo+="<th>";
    conteudo+="<div class='situacao'><p>Situacao</p></div>";
      conteudo+="</th>";
     conteudo+="</tr>";
    //pos contator
    for(var pos=0;pos<nomes.length;pos++){
        conteudo+="<tr>";

        conteudo+="<td>"+nomes[pos]+"</td>";
        conteudo+="<td>"+media[pos]+"</td>";
        conteudo+="<td>"+situacao[pos]+"</td>";

        conteudo+="</tr>";
    }
    conteudo+="</table>";
    document.getElementById("txtrelatorio").innerHTML=conteudo;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tens vários problemas no código:

- situacao está definido duas vezes. Uma como função, outra como array
- Usa `Number()` á volta dos numeros, para os converter de texto em numero
- depois de `if (validar) {` dever ter os numeros pois vais compará-los no `if` seguinte, como tinhas estavam numa linha mais em baixo e por isso não tinham sido lidos ainda.

Sugestão:

```js
function validar() {
  var nome = $("#nome").val();
  var rgm = $("#rgm").val();
  var parcial = Number($("#notaparcial").val());
  var exercicios = Number($("#notaexercicios").val());
  var projeto = Number($("#notaprojeto").val());
  var regimental = Number($("#notaregimental").val());

  if (nome == "") {
    alert('Preencha o campo com seu nome');
    form1.nome.focus();
  } else if (rgm == "") {
    alert('Preencha o campo com rgm');
    form1.rgm.focus();

  } else if (parcial == 0) {
    alert('Preencha o campo com a nota da parcial');
    form1.rgm.focus();

  } else if (exercicios == 0) {
    alert('Preencha o campo com a nota dos exe');
    form1.exercicios.focus();

  } else if (projeto == 0) {
    alert('Preencha o campo com a nota projeto');
    form1.projeto.focus();

  } else {
    alert('Preencha o campo com a nota regimental');
    form1.notaregimental.focus();
  }
}

function caculoMedia( /* n1, n2, n3, n4, etc */ ) {
  return [].reduce.call(arguments, function(sum, nr) {
    return sum + nr;
  }, 0) / (arguments.length);
}

function situacao(n1, n2, n3, n4) {
  var situacao = "";
  var media = caculoMedia(n1, n2, n3, n4);
  if (media >= 6) situacao += "Aprovado";
  else if (media < 6) situacao += "Exame";
  else situacao += "Reprovado";
  return situacao;
}


var nomes = [];
var indice = [];
var sit = [];
var media = [];

var i = 1;


window.onload = function() {
  var btn = document.getElementById("btncalcular");
  btn.onclick = function() {
    if (validar) {
      var parcial = Number($("#notaparcial").val());
      var exercicios = Number($("#notaexercicios").val());
      var projeto = Number($("#notaprojeto").val());
      var regimental = Number($("#notaregimental").val());
      console.log(parcial, exercicios, projeto, regimental);
      if (parcial + exercicios + projeto + regimental <= 10) {
        nomes[i] = $("#nome").val();


        var resp = caculoMedia(parcial, exercicios, projeto, regimental);
        media[i] = resp;
        var sit = situacao(parcial, exercicios, projeto, regimental);
        sit[i] = situacao;
      } else {
        alert("A soma das notas não podem ultrapassar 10");
      }
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("btnlistar").onclick = function() {
    listarAlunos();
  }
}



function listarAlunos() {
  var conteudo = "<table border='2'>";
  conteudo += "<tr>";
  conteudo += "<th>";
  conteudo += "<div class='aluno'><p>Aluno</p></div>";
  conteudo += "</th>";
  conteudo += "<th>";
  conteudo += "<div class='media'><p>Media</p></div>";
  conteudo += "</th>";
  conteudo += "<th>";
  conteudo += "<div class='situacao'><p>Situacao</p></div>";
  conteudo += "</th>";
  conteudo += "</tr>";
  //pos contator
  for (var pos = 0; pos < nomes.length; pos++) {
    conteudo += "<tr>";

    conteudo += "<td>" + nomes[pos] + "</td>";
    conteudo += "<td>" + media[pos] + "</td>";
    conteudo += "<td>" + sit[pos] + "</td>";

    conteudo += "</tr>";
  }
  conteudo += "</table>";
  document.getElementById("txtrelatorio").innerHTML = conteudo;
}
```

```css
.formcss {
  width: 55%;
  background-color: #865027;
  padding: 20px 30px 20px 30px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: verdana;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
  padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
}

.titulo {
  font-size: 11px;
}

div {
  margin: 0px 0px 20px;
}

.rotulos {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.rotuloretorno {
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: verdana;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 200px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.entrada {
  border: none;
  color: #525252;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 15px;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
  width: 70%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;
  background-color: #f5deb3;
}

.botao {
  background-color: #2e1707;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFE477;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #3D3D3D;
}

.botao:hover {
  color: #dbd9d9;
  background-color: #030201;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" class="formcss" name="form1">
  <h1>Dados do Aluno<br/>
    <span class="titulo">Por favor, preencha os campos solicitados.</span>
  </h1>
  <div>&nbsp;</div>
  <div>
    <div class="rotulos">RGM :</div>
    <input id="rgm" type="text" name="rgm" placeholder="Digite seu RGM" class="entrada" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="rotulos">Nome :</div>
      <input id="nome" type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome completo" class="entrada" />
    </div>

    <div>
      <div class="rotulos">Nota parcial :</div>
      <input type="text" id="notaparcial" name="notaparcial" placeholder="Digite aqui a nota parcial" class="entrada" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="rotulos">Nota exercícios :</div>
      <input type="text" id="notaexercicios" name="notaexercicios" placeholder="Digite aqui a nota dos exercícios" class="entrada" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="rotulos">Nota projeto :</div>
      <input type="text" id="notaprojeto" name="notaprojeto" placeholder="Digite aqui a nota no projeto" class="entrada" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="rotulos">Nota regimental :</div>
      <input type="text" id="notaregimental" name="notaregimental" placeholder="Digite aqui a nota regimental" class="entrada" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="rotulos">&nbsp;</div>
      <input type="button" id="btncalcular" value="Calcular" class="botao" />
      <input type="button" id="btnlistar" value="Mostrar" class="botao" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <div id="divresultado" class="rotuloretorno">Resultado...</div>
    </div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div><br>
</form>
```